# i am making z80 pio program , but i find some error with the code for JRNZ

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, z80

if data input PORT A=08H then data output PORT B=0FH, and if the data input PORT A = 80H then data output PORT B = F0H , other than these the output PORT B = 00H
Here is my code

```
      LD     A, 4FH
      OUT    (82H), A
      LD     A, 0FH
      OUT    (83H), A

LOOP:   IN     A, (80H)
        CP     08H
        JRNZ   STATE1
        LD     B,0FH
        JR     RESULT
STATE1: CP     80H
        JRNZ   STATE2
        LD     B,F0H
        JR     RESULT
STATE2: LD     B,00H
RESULT: OUT    (81H), A
        JP     LOOP
```

Error : unrecognized instruction. 'JRNZ +-'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `JR NZ,label`? (i.e. a space between `JR` and `NZ`).

Comment: https://clrhome.org/table/#jr

Comment: You were probably thinking of `djnz`.

Answer (score 3):

The standard Z-80 mnemonics separate condition codes from the opcode.  In other words, `JRNZ` is not a valid Z-80 opcode.  You should separate it like this:

```
    JR    NZ,STATE1
...
    JR    NZ,STATE2
```

Incidentally, there's a bug in your program.  You need to load register A with B before doing the output.

```
RESULT: LD     A,B
        OUT    (81H), A
        JP     LOOP
```

Or you could use the `OUT (C),reg` variant:

```
RESULT: LD     C,81H
        OUT    (C),B
        JP     LOOP
```

You can also make the program a little shorter if you load the output value in anticipation of matching the input.  Like so:

```
LOOP:   IN     A,(80H)
        LD     B,0FH
        CP     08H
        JR     Z,RESULT
        LD     B,F0H
        CP     80H
        JR     Z,RESULT
        LD     B,00H
RESULT: LD     A,B
        OUT    (81H),A
        JP     LOOP
```